# Border Wall GoFundMe - Is It Possible to Donate Money to the Government for a Specific Purpose?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

A recent [gofundme](https://www.gofundme.com/TheTrumpWall) page is seeking to crowd fund Trump's proposed border wall. Assuming that this is a genuine attempt to raise the money rather than a scam or political stunt, is it even possible for an indidividual or group of individuals to donate money to the US Government *and* have it ear marked for a specific purpose? I have no doubt that you can [donate](https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/public/gifts-to-government.html) to the us government, but that comes with two specific caveats:

> Money deposited into this account is for general use by the federal government and can be available for budget needs.

and

> These contributions are considered an unconditional gift to the government.

In short, is it possible to donate money to the government for a specific purpose and get anything better than a promise that it will be used for what you say it will?

Comment: @DavidRice That does seem relevant. I didn't find that question when I was searching. However, I'm not sure if it specifically answers whether or not this donation could be earmarked or not to fund the wall. The key seems to be "However, most other agencies can't accept such donations, and no agency can use donated money to fund its mission without Congressional approval." So it would require congressional approval, can DHS accept donations? This [link](https://www.dhs.gov/archive/information-donations) seems to imply no.

Comment: I think, though I'm not sure, that you can donate a gift to the agency which gets earmarked for use by the agency but which cannot be used until and unless Congress provides their approval.

Comment: As a note it seems there is a one billion dollar limit on go fund me that the organizer of that fundraiser is trying to change.

Comment: Maybe we could differentiate the question by asking whether the executive can direct money from a donation, designated to a specific purpose, to that purpose; without congressional approval.

Comment: I doubt this is workable. If I provided funding for a war, we would not be required to go to war.

Comment: Incidentally, [the GoFundMe has run into some legal trouble](https://www.thedailybeast.com/gofundme-border-wall-campaign-implodes-turns-to-kris-kobach-and-sheriff-clarke-for-new-non-profit) and some of the money is being refunded and some of the money is being shuffled around. Regardless of what you think about the wall, I'd recommend *not* contributing to this.